# How to create Recruiting manager using Facebook for creating XML Job feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We need to implement XML Job posting for our Application's Career Portal. We have tried by following Graph API but it is giving following error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "E4LF9xlAzNl"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you got any solution yet ?